# The division of Riemann - Stieltjes integral on intervals

Tags: integration, proof-verification

I am to proof that:
$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dg(x) = \int\limits_{a}^{c}f(x)dg(x) + \int\limits_{c}^{b}f(x)dg(x)$
where $a<c<b$ and $f(x)$ is g - integrable.
I started with the definition:
$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dg(x) = lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{2n}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta g_{i}$
Now:
We divide $ab$ on $2n$ parts, where $a = x_{0}, ..., b = x_{n}$
$x_{i}^{*}$ is any point in a segment $I_{i} = x_{i} - x_{i-1}$
$\Delta g_{i} = g(x_{i}) - g(x_{i-1})$
And my next step was:
$lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{2n}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta g_{i} = lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta g_{i} + lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{i = n + 1}^{2n}f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta g_{i}$
However I really don't know if is valuable and I don't know if I can easily finish my proof with that written above.

Comment: How did you define that $f$ is $g$-integrable?

Comment: In some books, they assume that the integrator $g$ is increasing and some assume it a function of variation. What about yours?

Comment: Actually in my books two versions were given and there was a proof that they are equivalent thus assume as you wish